Finding the right change of variables.
Consider the following expression: $$f=x_{13}^2 x_{22} + 2 x_{12} x_{13} x_{23} - 2 \sqrt{x_{11}} x_{13} \sqrt{x_{22}} x_{23} + x_{11} x_{23}^2 - 2 x_{12} x_{13} \sqrt{x_{22}} \sqrt{x_{33}} - 2 \sqrt{x_{11}} x_{12} x_{23} \sqrt{x_{33}} + x_{12}^2 x_{33} + x_{11} x_{22} x_{33}
$$
I am looking for a change of variables $\{y_{12},y_{13},y_{23}\}$ such that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_{12}}=2 (x_{12}-\sqrt{x_{11}}\sqrt{x_{22}}),$$ $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_{13}}=2 (x_{13}-\sqrt{x_{11}}\sqrt{x_{33}}),$$ $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_{23}}=2 (x_{23}-\sqrt{x_{22}}\sqrt{x_{33}}),$$ after all the $y_{ij}$'s have been changed back to $x_{ij}$'s.
Note that $$y_{12}=x_{13} x_{23},\quad  y_{13}=x_{12}x_{23},\quad  y_{23}=x_{12}x_{13}$$ almost works. However, there are a couple of extra terms that I would wish to not have.
This question has naturally come up in my research, and I am looking for an ideal coordinate system in which the derivatives of this function are particularly simple.
